# Chrome Extension - Schedule task overnight

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download, schedule

I'm making a Chrome extension and I would like to be able to run a function that downloads a series of files at a certain time, which most likely would be at night. I have my file downloading function sorted out, so I just need to be able to run code at a certain time.

Please note that the computer may be in sleep mode when the function is scheduled to run, this is the reason why I don't think a simple `setTimeout` would work properly and so why I'm asking this question.

Comment: I doubt any chrome extension will wake a computer from sleep

Comment: What about the `chrome.alarms` API? Would setting an alarm using that wake up an asleep computer? Given that it is possible to schedule tasks overnight by other means like Window's task scheduler, I think it is a possibility. The only problem is testing that would be a pain, as I'd have to work out how the API works, write a test, and wait for my computer to sleep.

Comment: the [chrome.alarms](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms) API isn't rocket surgery

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok. (Rocket _surgery_?)

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to make an accompanying utility that runs natively in OS and uses the low-level OS API to set the alarms capable of waking up the computer. And use Chrome native messaging API to communicate with the extension.